# How does alberuni's translation of patanjali's yoga sutras differ from traditional yoga sutras?

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras

Wikipedia says that there is difference between the translation of alberuni and actual text. While some changes were introduced by alberuni because of Islam, 
How is the philosophy of both different?